# Is it possible to merge two pandas dataframes based on column name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
left = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "Col": ["D", "C", "B", "A"],
        },
    )
right = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "A": ["A0"],
            "B": ["B0"],
            "C": ["C0"],
            "D": ["D0"],
        },
    )
```

Is it possible to merge them based on `col` of the left and column names on the right ?

I need to get the following result:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "Col": ["D", "C", "B", "A"],
            "Val": ["D0", "C0", "B0", "A0"],
        },
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) with the transposition ([`T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html#pandas-dataframe-t) or [`transpose()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html#pandas-dataframe-transpose)):

```
import pandas as pd

left = pd.DataFrame({
    "Col": ["D", "C", "B", "A"],
})
right = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": ["A0"],
    "B": ["B0"],
    "C": ["C0"],
    "D": ["D0"],
})

new_df = left.join(right.T, on='Col').rename(columns={0: 'Val'})
print(new_df)
```

`new_df`:

```
  Col Val
0   D  D0
1   C  C0
2   B  B0
3   A  A0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a pretty straightforward `.map`:

```
In [319]: left['Val'] = left['Col'].map(right.T[0])

In [320]: left
Out[320]:
  Col Val
0   D  D0
1   C  C0
2   B  B0
3   A  A0
```